# OnBeforeSendHeaders update filter list on the fly or best way to sequentially use events onBeforeRequest and onBeforeSendHeaders

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to block requests from a website in a chrome extension that I am making.

I'm currently using `onBeforeRequest` to look at the incoming traffic and decide which ones I will block, I then intend to use that array as the filter list to block in a later stage such as `onBeforeSendHeaders`.

Now I currently have two problems, firstly if I implement it the way I have below it's very inefficient as some websites have hundreds of things coming in which means the event is being attached and detached too often.

Secondly, If I am just declaring the listener at the start the filter list doesn't use the updated version - I assume that when it registers it takes a copy of the filter list not a reference to the memory, I tried with a function etc instead.

Any help in optimising this / the best way to have that list work would be grateful.

```
var urlstoblock = [];

//Listen to all incoming requests and filter them
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener
(
    FilterRequests,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestBody"]
);


function FilterRequests(info)
{
    urlstoblock.push("*://*.lol123.com/*");
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.removeListener(DomainBlock);
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
        DomainFilter,
        {urls: urlstoblock},
        ["blocking"]
    );
}

function DomainFilter(){
    return {cancel : true};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters for an existing listener can't be changed dynamically so indeed the only way is to remove the listener and add it with the new filter.

In your case it might be better to intercept all requests. The final decision should be based on performance measurements because a hundred of requests isn't something inherently impressive. You can use devtools profiler or chrome://tracing for in-depth analysis.

A possible workaround is to create a new function reference each time:

```
const blockedUrls = new Map();
const blocker = () => ({cancel: true});

const registerBlocker = url => {
  const fn = blocker.bind(null);
  blockedUrls.set(url, fn);
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(fn, {urls: [url]}, ['blocking']);
};

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  info => registerBlocker('*://*.lol123.com/*'),
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['requestBody'],
);
```

The new listener function is stored in blockedUrls only to allow you to unregister it afterwards.

Comment: Works brilliant thanks, How can I use the map to detatch each of the listeners, haven't really used them before. I'm sending a message from the page to the Background to tell it the doc is ready and then do I just loop over the map and run ```chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blocker);``` on each item and pop it from the map>?

Comment: Yes, e.g. blockUrls.forEach(fn => blabla.removeListener(fn)); blockUrls.clear();

Comment: Brilliant, big help, I'm working on a university project, is it okay to use(with modification) and reference these posts and material?

Comment: It depends on your uni's policy if it exists for such cases. StackOverflow itself uses Creative Commons License which allows personal/noncommercial use, see the help section for more info.

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look and make a descision!